# Comparison of Cuda Shared Memory Copies: Which Approach Better

Tags: cuda

When coping an array to another array in shared memory, I tried six different approaches (see comments in the program). After discussions and testings, my conclusions are:
(1) memcpy is not faster than element-wise copy of an array.
(2) For small array, approach 3 is the best. For larger array, approach 6 is the best.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

const int NUM_OF_BLOCKS = 1;
const int NUM_OF_THREADS_PER_BLOCK = 8;
const int NUM_OF_DATA = 6000;
const int NUM_OF_COPIES= 1000;
//const int NUM_OF_COPIES= 1000000;

cudaError_t cuda_status;

__shared__ int start_index[NUM_OF_THREADS_PER_BLOCK];
__shared__ int end_index[NUM_OF_THREADS_PER_BLOCK];
__shared__ int src[NUM_OF_DATA];
__shared__ int dest[NUM_OF_DATA];

using namespace std;

__device__ void init(){
   unsigned int num_of_data_per_thread = NUM_OF_DATA / NUM_OF_THREADS_PER_BLOCK;
   unsigned int extra_data = NUM_OF_DATA % NUM_OF_THREADS_PER_BLOCK;
   int size[NUM_OF_THREADS_PER_BLOCK];

   start_index[threadIdx.x] = threadIdx.x * num_of_data_per_thread;

   if (threadIdx.x < extra_data){
       start_index[threadIdx.x] = start_index[threadIdx.x] + threadIdx.x;
       size[threadIdx.x] = num_of_data_per_thread + 1;
   }else{
       start_index[threadIdx.x] = start_index[threadIdx.x] + extra_data;
       size[threadIdx.x] = num_of_data_per_thread ;
   }

   end_index[threadIdx.x] = start_index[threadIdx.x] + size[threadIdx.x] -1;
   //printf("start_index[%d] = %d, end_index[%d] = %d\n", threadIdx.x, start_index[threadIdx.x], threadIdx.x, end_index[threadIdx.x]);
}

__device__ void inc_src_data(int* src){
  int i;

  for (i = 0; i < NUM_OF_DATA; i++, src++){
      *src += 1;
  }
  //__threadfence_block();
}

template <int sel>
__device__ void copy_to_dest_array(int* src, int* dest){
   int i;

   switch (sel){
   case 1:

   // Approach 1: every thread executes memcpy
   memcpy(dest, src, NUM_OF_DATA * sizeof(int));
   break;

   case 2:
   // Approach 2: one thread executes memcpy and then threadfence
   if (threadIdx.x == 0){
      memcpy(dest, src, NUM_OF_DATA * sizeof(int));
      __threadfence_block();
   }
   break;
   case 3:
   // Approach 3: every thread copies each element individually
   for (i = 0; i < NUM_OF_DATA; i++, dest++, src++)
       *dest = *src;
      //__threadfence_block();  // added this line to demonstrate timing difference
   break;
   case 4:
   // Approach 4: one thread copy each element individually and then threadfence
   if (threadIdx.x == 0)
       for (i = 0; i < NUM_OF_DATA; i++, dest++, src++)
            *dest = *src;
   __threadfence_block();
   break;
   case 5:
   // Approach 5: every thread execute memcpy and then threadfence
   memcpy(dest+start_index[threadIdx.x], src + start_index[threadIdx.x], (end_index[threadIdx.x] - start_index[threadIdx.x] + 1) * sizeof(int));
   __threadfence_block();
   break;
   case 6:
   // Approach 6: every thread copies each element individually and then threadfence
   for (i = start_index[threadIdx.x]; i <= end_index[threadIdx.x]; i++){
       dest[i] = src[i];
   }
   __threadfence_block();
   break;
   default:
   assert(0);
   break;
   }
}

template <int sel>
__global__ void copy_data_test(int* data){
   init();

   copy_to_dest_array<sel>(data, src);

   for (int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_COPIES; i++){
       inc_src_data(src);
       copy_to_dest_array<sel>(&src[0], &dest[0]);
   }
   copy_to_dest_array<sel>(dest, data);

}

template <int sel>
__global__ void copy_data_test(int* data){
   init();

   copy_to_dest_array<sel>(data, src);

   for (int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_COPIES; i++){
       inc_src_data(src);
       copy_to_dest_array<sel>(&src[0], &dest[0]);
   }
   copy_to_dest_array<sel>(dest, data);

}

template <int sel>
void run_test(int *rdata, int *hdata, int *ddata){
  cudaEvent_t start, stop;
  cudaEventCreate(&start); cudaEventCreate(&stop);
  cudaMemcpy(ddata, hdata, NUM_OF_DATA * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  cudaEventRecord(start);
  copy_data_test<sel><<<NUM_OF_BLOCKS, NUM_OF_THREADS_PER_BLOCK>>>(ddata);
  cudaEventRecord(stop);
  cout << "kernel error: " << cudaGetErrorString(cudaPeekAtLastError()) << "---" << cudaGetErrorString(cudaDeviceSynchronize()) << endl;

  cudaMemcpy(rdata, ddata, NUM_OF_DATA * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
  float et;
  cudaEventElapsedTime(&et, start, stop);
  cout << "Trial " << sel << " elapsed time: " << et << "ms" << endl;
/*
  cout << "after kernel processing" << endl;
  for (int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_DATA; i++)
      cout << rdata[i] << " ";
  cout << endl;
*/
  cudaEventDestroy(start);
  cudaEventDestroy(stop);

}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
  int h_data[NUM_OF_DATA];
  int r_data[NUM_OF_DATA];
  int* d_data;
  int i;

  cudaSetDevice(0);

  srand(time(NULL));
/*
  cout << "before kernel processing" << endl;
  for (i = 0; i < NUM_OF_DATA; i++){
      h_data[i] = rand()%100;
      cout << h_data[i] << " ";
  }
  cout << endl;
*/
  cudaMalloc(&d_data, sizeof(int) * NUM_OF_DATA);

  run_test<1>(r_data, h_data, d_data);
  run_test<2>(r_data, h_data, d_data);
  run_test<3>(r_data, h_data, d_data);
  run_test<4>(r_data, h_data, d_data);
  run_test<5>(r_data, h_data, d_data);
  run_test<6>(r_data, h_data, d_data);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The actual copying you are doing (e.g. from `src` to `dest`) does not involve shared memory.  Those are thread-local variable definitions.  Furthermore, a common mistake when benchmarking is to write code that generates no externally visible state.  If you don't change anything that is somehow visible in results produced by the kernel, then the compiler is free to optimize away any code that doesn't do anything "useful".  Your code(s) as presented do nothing useful, and I suspect the timing results will not be meaningful because the compiler is optimizing things in a way you don't expect.

Comment: Updated the program so that both src and dest are in shared memory, and added more approaches for comparisons.

Comment: Corrected errors for not guarding src and dest. Then the results are more close to expectation. Still curious that extra memory copies does not slow down the performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems fairly clear that the `__threadfence_block()` is an expensive operation.  The 4 longest test cases all use `__threadfence_block()`.  The two shortest test cases do not.

If I add `__threadfence_block()` to the 3rd (i.e. the shortest) test case, the timing (for me) changes from ~2 sec to ~17 sec.

Note that your test cases are not all doing the exact same thing, as evidenced by the difference in the output results.  I made a modified version of your code that more clearly demonstrates this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

const int NUM_OF_BLOCKS = 1;
const int NUM_OF_THREADS_PER_BLOCK = 8;
const int NUM_OF_DATA = 50;
const int NUM_OF_COPIES= 10000000;

cudaError_t cuda_status;

__shared__ int start_index[NUM_OF_THREADS_PER_BLOCK];
__shared__ int end_index[NUM_OF_THREADS_PER_BLOCK];
__shared__ int src[NUM_OF_DATA];
__shared__ int dest[NUM_OF_DATA];

using namespace std;

__device__ void init(){
   unsigned int num_of_data_per_thread = NUM_OF_DATA / NUM_OF_THREADS_PER_BLOCK;
   unsigned int extra_data = NUM_OF_DATA % NUM_OF_THREADS_PER_BLOCK;
   int size[NUM_OF_THREADS_PER_BLOCK];

   start_index[threadIdx.x] = threadIdx.x * num_of_data_per_thread;

   if (threadIdx.x < extra_data){
       start_index[threadIdx.x] = start_index[threadIdx.x] + threadIdx.x;
       size[threadIdx.x] = num_of_data_per_thread + 1;
   }else{
       start_index[threadIdx.x] = start_index[threadIdx.x] + extra_data;
       size[threadIdx.x] = num_of_data_per_thread ;
   }

   end_index[threadIdx.x] = start_index[threadIdx.x] + size[threadIdx.x] -1;
}

__device__ void inc_src_data(int* src){
  int i;

  for (i = 0; i < NUM_OF_DATA; i++, src++){
      *src += 1;
  }
  //__threadfence_block();
}

template <int sel>
__device__ void copy_to_dest_array(int* src, int* dest){
   int i;

   switch (sel){
   case 1:

   // Approach 1: every thread executes memcpy
   memcpy(dest, src, NUM_OF_DATA);
   break;

   case 2:
   // Approach 2: one thread executes memcpy and then threadfence
   if (threadIdx.x == 0){
      memcpy(dest, src, NUM_OF_DATA);
      __threadfence_block();
   }
   break;
   case 3:
   // Approach 3: every thread copies each element individually
   for (i = 0; i < NUM_OF_DATA; i++, dest++, src++)
       *dest = *src;
      __threadfence_block();  // added this line to demonstrate timing difference
   break;
   case 4:
   // Approach 4: one thread copy each element individually and then threadfence
   if (threadIdx.x == 0)
       for (i = 0; i < NUM_OF_DATA; i++, dest++, src++)
            *dest = *src;
   __threadfence_block();
   break;
   case 5:
   // Approach 5: every thread execute memcpy and then threadfence
   memcpy(dest+start_index[threadIdx.x], src + start_index[threadIdx.x], end_index[threadIdx.x] - start_index[threadIdx.x] + 1);
   __threadfence_block();
   break;
   case 6:
   // Approach 6: every thread copies each element individually and then threadfence
   for (i = start_index[threadIdx.x]; i <= end_index[threadIdx.x]; i++){
       *(dest + i) = *(src + i);
   }
   __threadfence_block();
   break;
   default:
   assert(0);
   break;
   }
}

template <int sel>
__global__ void copy_data_test(int* data){
   init();

   copy_to_dest_array<sel>(data, src);

   for (int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_COPIES; i++){
       inc_src_data(src);
       copy_to_dest_array<sel>(&src[0], &dest[0]);
   }
   copy_to_dest_array<sel>(dest, data);

}

template <int sel>
void run_test(int *rdata, int *hdata, int *ddata){
  cudaEvent_t start, stop;
  cudaEventCreate(&start); cudaEventCreate(&stop);
  cudaMemcpy(ddata, hdata, NUM_OF_DATA * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  cudaEventRecord(start);
  copy_data_test<sel><<<NUM_OF_BLOCKS, NUM_OF_THREADS_PER_BLOCK>>>(ddata);
  cudaEventRecord(stop);
  cout << "kernel error: " << cudaGetErrorString(cudaPeekAtLastError()) << "---" << cudaGetErrorString(cudaDeviceSynchronize()) << endl;

  cudaMemcpy(rdata, ddata, NUM_OF_DATA * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
  float et;
  cudaEventElapsedTime(&et, start, stop);
  cout << "Trial " << sel << " elapsed time: " << et << "ms" << endl;
  cout << "after kernel processing" << endl;
  for (int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_DATA; i++)
      cout << rdata[i] << " ";
  cout << endl;
  cudaEventDestroy(start);
  cudaEventDestroy(stop);

}



int main(int argc, char **argv){
  int h_data[NUM_OF_DATA];
  int r_data[NUM_OF_DATA];
  int* d_data;
  int i;

  cudaSetDevice(0);

  srand(time(NULL));
  cout << "before kernel processing" << endl;
  for (i = 0; i < NUM_OF_DATA; i++){
      h_data[i] = rand()%100;
      cout << h_data[i] << " ";
  }
  cout << endl;
  cudaMalloc(&d_data, sizeof(int) * NUM_OF_DATA);

  run_test<1>(r_data, h_data, d_data);
  run_test<2>(r_data, h_data, d_data);
  run_test<3>(r_data, h_data, d_data);
  run_test<4>(r_data, h_data, d_data);
  run_test<5>(r_data, h_data, d_data);
  run_test<6>(r_data, h_data, d_data);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. I corrected errors in my original program (multiple threads modify src and dest concurrently). After the modification, the conclusion is the same for that threadfence_block is expensive, but different for that now approach 1 is the fastest even though extra memory copies are done.

Comment: Ok, I had to take back my words: some 'errors' are not errors. The one I believe to be correct is posted above. In summary, (1) memcpy is not faster than each individual element copy (is this because of laze write, i.e., new values stay in registers?). (2) redundant memory copies (element wise) is faster because no need to threadfence_block. My guess this is still because of those values are stored in registers. I tested with larger array (5000, 6000 integers). Results show that the last approach is the fastest one: 195ms vs 270 ms